# Best option for making a collection of python code portable?

Tags: python

Here are the facts:

- I have a collection of python scripts that work together as part of a program
- It takes a user input and outputs `.docx` and `.excel` files
- Right now, only executable through command-line/editor (i.e. you call one script, it does the rest)
- Non-CS people have difficulties downloading the necessary modules, and running the program

I want to make my program easily executable/portable to different OSs. So far, I have the following options:

- Create a website that takes input visually, and does what it has to do. How do I get the website to refer to my code? Do I have to put it in some sort of web server?
- Create an executable that others can simply run (Not sure if this is possible)
- Create a GUI that does everything visually.

What are the pros and cons of each one of these options? Which one would you say is most feasible?

My apologies if I said something silly. I'm still learning most of this stuff.

Thank you!

Comment: In general, you should model the core functional part of the code as simple classes and functions which can be called with input and will return/output the result (as opposed to "scripts" which just run and then exit). You can then wrap that core functionality into any interface you want, including command line scripts, websites or GUIs.

Comment: So, modularize my code. That should be simple. But then what?

Comment: Yes, modularise. From there, again, look at the UI as a separate project. If you want a web UI, pick a Python web framework to create an HTML page which calls your modules on the backend. Same for other CLI or GUI interfaces. Which option to choose is not something we can help you with, that's up to you and your use case.

Comment: For packaging your scripts as executables, one option is [PyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller).